# How to copy (or duplicate) an entire folder in Vim using NERDTree?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I know how to create a folder in NERDTree: `m + a` then `newfolder/`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`m + c` on the folder would duplicate it